# Updating Entity Framework Models after database change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework and I decided to try the Code First route. It's worked out so far, but I had to add a table and some foreign key relationships to the database. There seems to be no way to update this. I understand that "code first" means that it shouldn't depend on the database, but what if I need to make a change to the database?

Is there a way to properly generate my new models from the database?

Comment: Typically you'd make the changes to your models (code-first) then perform a [migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Comment: I have never try this, but if you are using EF 6.1+ then you can generate your code first model from database: (Channel 9 video)(http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Code-First-to-Existing-Database-EF6-1-Onwards-). And just one question, are you using Migrations or not?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found around this is to make the changes to your POCOs, and then build the migration, and use the flag `-Script` in your powershell console when updating the database like so:

```
Update-Database -Script -Force -ProjectName 'MyProject'
```

which will then create a SQL script for you of the changes, then only execute the last part that is inserting a row in the `MigrationHistory` table. Now EF is aware of the changes and thinks that they have been applied to the database.

However if you are using explicit mappings (either attributes or the FluentAPI), then you might even be able to get away without needing to update anything. In my experience EF won't know the difference.

Comment: Hmm...I opted for Code First because I know they're phasing out the Database First method, but this seems kinda broken for data-centric systems.

Comment: Well, that is more complicated than that, EF6 will continue to support both database first, code first and designer methods, EF7 will not be compatible, but will also require significant rewrite on your part to upgrade to. All my method does is fake EF into thinking that it is up to date with the database, this method also allows you to fake FK's and change types(which EF is not that great at handling). - However, you can always make your changes code first rather than making them in the database directly.